# Magento admin is giving problems

Tags: php, magento, magento2

When I work in the backend of magento I get to see a screen with different actions as you will see in my screenshot.

The actions that I do are as follows:

I go from catalog to Categories and then click on a category. Then he shows the page as in the screenshot.

Even if I go to articles and then set the results per page to 200, for example, he will load the page as shown in the screenshot.

Cache is on. However, as soon as I disable cache, I no longer have this problem. I have installed a number of modules that seem to work fine.

If I do an element inspection and then console in chrome I get the result as I show in screenshot2.

Thank you very much for the help.

http://www.privatelabelsportvoeding.nl/screenshot.PNG

http://www.privatelabelsportvoeding.nl/screenshot2.PNG

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The generated folder was owned by user root. Thats why all the items did not worked well.